# Metal Compute - enqueue an already enqueued command buffer

Tags: swift, gpgpu, metal

I'm very new to Metal and I am experimenting with its compute functionalities.
I have the following piece of code written in Swift 3 on macOS:

```
repeat
{ 
    metalCommandBuffer.enqueue()
    metalCommandBuffer.commit()
    metalCommandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
    copy variable back to CPU
}
while {check the variable == 0}
```

I want to execute a compute kernel, copy the variable back to the host and check if some condition is met. If it is then continue to execute the kernel until otherwise.

However I get the following error:

> error 'enqueue an already enqueued command buffer'

I have tried just having the commit and waitUntilCompleted inside the loop but then I get:

> error 'commit an already committed command buffer'

I have a bit of CUDA knowledge and as a result of that I may be somewhat misusing Metal.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reuse a command buffer like that.

You have to create a new command buffer, create a new compute command encoder, encode the command(s), end encoding, and then commit the command buffer every time through the loop.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a need to dispose/clear the memory used by the previous buffer and encoder or is that not necessary?

Comment: The objects will be released when you clear or re-set the strong references to them, or allow them to go out of scope. Swift uses Automatic Reference Counting, so there's nothing special you need to do.